# Synaptic package manager is not starting in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I cannot start Synaptic by clicking on the icon and when I type sudo synaptic I get this message:

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyFailed to connect to Mir: Failed to
 connect to server socket: No such file or directory Unable to init
 server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(synaptic:9789): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

I can start Synaptic without using sudo.

Comment: Do you have any shell configuration file (e.g. `.bashrc`) in which you've set the `DISPLAY` environment variable? There are a lot of questions dealing with the "Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE" message – what have you tried so far?

Comment: I just re-installed ubuntu. When I try to run a diagnostic for Comodo I get this message :  Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keycavdiagnostic: cannot connect to X server :0

Comment: You reinstalled from scratch and are still getting this message? That is weird. Not too much an expert on the Xorg server. If you're not getting an answer here within, say, a day, you may flag for this to be migrated to [ubuntu.SE].